# Is there a way to get TexMakerX to recognize commands defined in an input file?

Tags: macros, input, texmaker

I have a file that defines a bunch of commands for various variables that I use in other documents.  Here's a small example of what it contains:

```
\newcommand{\varElevation}{\ensuremath{\alpha_{el}}}
\newcommand{\varAzimuth}{\ensuremath{\alpha_{az}}}
\newcommand{\varRoll}{\ensuremath{\phi}}
\newcommand{\varPitch}{\ensuremath{\theta}}
\newcommand{\varYaw}{\ensuremath{\psi}}
```

I use the `input{...}` command to insert the above file into the preambles of the documents that use those variables (thus making it very easy to change the symbols I use for the variables across multiple documents).  Although the documents build correctly, TexMakerX highlights all calls to those custom commands as "unrecognized commands."  Is there a way to get TexMakerX to parse the input file as well so that the syntax highlighting is correct?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes it would be nice to vote if no pleas tell me why it didn’t help.

Comment: @Tobi: Thanks for the answer.  I was trying out a few different editors looking for a feature that I wanted (preserved indentation for word-wrapped lines) and was annoyed at this highlighting issue with TexMakerX (which has now been renamed to TeXstudio).  Ultimately, I settled on building my own version of TeXnicCenter from source since the indentation feature was implemented soon after the latest alpha release.  Your answer does seem like a workaround, but it also seems like the only way to address the problem since no one else has chimed in.  BTW, the renaming to TeXstudio broke your links.

Comment: OK. Thanks for telling me the broken links. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to create an own [CWL-File](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION) but this seems to be a workauround in your case.
Unfortunatly I couldn’t finde out where to put these files, but I’m still searching …

### Update

The files should be in the config directory which is `~/.config/benibela` or `c:\Documents and Settings/User/AppData/Roaming/benibela`. See [1.4 Configuring the autocompletion](http://texstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/texstudio/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040) in the manual. (Mac see below at *Update 3*)

### Update 2

I tried to make an example an it didn’t work. It seems that the given path is wrong, so I ask the developer of tmx for help and give the next update with the (hopefully) working path an an example.

### Update 3

Now I got an answer from the developer and at the moment the configfiles on a **Mac** are only searched in the `.app`-Folder: `/Contents/Resources/completion`